# C# Awesomium Web Control - automatically download and open files

Tags: c#, web-controls, awesomium

I currently have an *Awesomium* Webvcontrol in my WinForms application. When I click a download link it prompts with a save file dialog.

I need it to download the file to a preset location and automatically open it. I am using the latest version of Awesomium.

References:

```
using Awesomium.Windows.Forms;
using Awesomium.Core;
```

Has anyone an idea how to make the control point to a preset location?

Comment: Do you have an example what sort of "preset" location you mean?

Comment: It can just be to the downloads folder or temporary folder. It just needs to run once it had downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure a way around this.
I added an method to the download event of webcore.

```
Awesomium.Core.WebCore.Download += onDownload;
```

The method looks like this.

```
public static void onDownload(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
{       

    e.Handled = true;       

    using (WebClient Client = new WebClient())
    {
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo("Your Path"); 
            //replace Your Path with the path you wish to save the file including filename and extension

            Client.DownloadFile(e.Url.ToString(), file.FullName);
            //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Downloaded!");

            Process.Start(file.FullName);

    }               
}
```

This now downloads and opens the file. In my case it was a .exe application.